# how get inputs in PHP by condition?

Tags: php

Usually in **PHP** for getting input in php we use finction:

- readline()

that get All avilable inputs.

If i want to get the inputs until for example user enter "end" how can we do that ???

Comment: `while ($line !== 'end') readline()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do "infinite loop" until you reach required keyword.

```php
$keyword = 'end';
$line = null;

while ($line !== $keyword) {
    $line = readline();

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is get the read line, find the "end" tag and then trim the string

```
$endTag = "end"; //Set the end tag
$line = readline(); //Read the input

$endPos = strpos($line, $endTag); //Find the location of your endTag
echo substr($line, 0, $endPos); //Get the substring of your line from position 0 up to the location of your endTag
```

Alternatively you could also do and `explode($endTag,$line)` that will split your user's input into an array and just use the first item, but in general this is considered a bit "cleaner"

Comment: Why not compare it directly with `end`? You do not want for input `unending input` to end input sequence

Comment: You are correct, I was planning on adding that on the answer, but then the problem arises from having words like " ending" or whatever else...

Comment: Thank you both for your guidance ^_^